# how to push multiple values into an array in TCL

Tags: arrays, dictionary, tcl

I am trying to append the values to an array as below and it is not appending to the value list

```
while {[gets $fp line] != -1} {

    if { [regexp {Path Group: (\w+)} $line all group]} {
        set hash($group) {}
 
    } elseif {[regexp {\(VIOLATED\)\s+(-[0-9]*.[0-9]*)} $line all slack]} {
        puts "slack $slack\n"
         lappend hash($group) $slack     
    }

 }

parray hash
```

The output of the array hash is only the last value of the iteration bit not a list

expecting

Name { X Y Z}
Age {3 4 5:}

Comment: Sample input would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set group {}
while {[gets $fp line] != -1} {
  if { [regexp {Path Group: (\w+)} $line all group]} {
  } elseif {[regexp {\(VIOLATED\)\s+(-[0-9]*.[0-9]*)} $line all slack]} {
    puts "slack $slack\n"
    lappend hash($group) $slack     
  }
}
parray hash
```

- No need to set `hash($group)` on each matching because this will reset the contents of `hash($group)`.
- In `lappend hash($group)`, if the variable does not exist, it will be created automatically.

Comment: This works! I need to declare the group as a list too